# How to correctly ask "what is this in English/what does "__" that mean/what is this" + clarification on qui/que

Tags: questions

I know that in French there are three different ways to ask a question:

- Simply with intontation
- With inversion
- With "est-ce que" (and therefore no inversion)

I'm specifically asking about the last two ways for this question. In particular, I want to know if these phrases are correct:

> - Qu’est-ce que ça veut dire?
> - Que veut dire ça?
> - Qu’est-ce que “maman” veut dire?
> - Que veut dire “maman”?
> - Qu’est-ce que “maman” est en anglais?
> - Qu'est “maman” en anglais?
> - Qu'est-ce que c'est?
> - Qu'est ça?

Note that I'm simply using "maman" as an example; I do know what it means!
If some of these are not correct, please explain to me why not; since I always thought you simple take out the "est-ce que/qui" and switch the position of the verb(s) and subject.

Also, I'm not quite sure how when to use "qui/que". I used to think the "qui" would refer to the subject and "que" to the object but since you say "qu'est-ce que c'est" and not "qu-est-ce qui c'est" I'm not so sure anymore. Some clarification on this would be nice as well.

EDIT: I really would like the last part of my question answered as well. Why is it "Qu'est-ce que c'est" and not "Qu'est-ce qui c'est"? Why is "qui" not appropriate here?

Comment: You wouldn't ask "what is this in English" but rather (among others)  "comment dit-on ça en anglais?" or "quel est l'équivalent en anglais?", literally "how does one say that in english" and "what is the English equivalent"

Comment: @antoine-sac My understanding is the question raised by the OP is asked by someone who do not understand some French word and ask for its English equivalent while "*Comment dit-on xxx en anglais ?*" is asked by someone who know what means the French word but want to know its English translation. That's a different situation.

Comment: EDIT : [**qui**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui) is about a person and [**que**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#Pronom_interrogatif) for inanimated things.

Comment: @YohannV. But is it not also that "qui" is for subjects and "que" is for objects of a sentence? For example, wouldn't you ask "Qu'est-ce qui lui a fait plaisir?" since you are asking about the *subject* of the sentence?

Comment: *"Qu'est-ce que c'est?"* = *What is **that**?* & *"Qu'est-ce qui lui fait plaisir?"* = *What is  making **him** happy?*

Comment: @YohannV. Yes, exactly; you would never say "Qu'est-ce que lui a fait plaisir" since you're asking about the subject of the sentence. **What** makes him happy. Therefore, in "Qu'est-ce que c'est", you're asking **What** is this.

Comment: So I don't see the difference between the two.

Comment: *What* carry the information about the question is about a thing. So does *Qu'est-ce* (= qu*e* *e*st-ce, different from *"qui est-ce"*). But in French, you also have information about if the subject is a thing or a person, held by qui/que.

Answer (score 2):

Correct:

- Qu’est-ce que ça veut dire ?

Correct, you need to clearly separate *maman* from the rest of the sentence, otherwise would mean "what does mum want to say?" :

- Qu’est-ce que « maman » veut dire ?
- Que veut dire « maman » ?

Not appropriate, this would be used for some unknown thing, not a word:

- Qu'est-ce que c'est ?

Non idiomatic / incorrect:

- Que veut dire ça ?
- Qu'est « maman » en anglais ?
- Qu’est-ce que « maman » est en anglais ?
- Qu'est ça ?

Note that I made some typographic changes, a space is required before a question mark in (France) French, and double quotes should be *guillemets*.

Comment: There is another form that OP didn't mention. I remember on kids cereal packs for example, when there was an informative question like "*what's an Okapi ?*" the question would be "*Qu'est-ce qu'un Okapi ?*". It's mostly literal though.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Yes, "*Qu'est-ce qu'un Okapi ?*" is how it is written and the form that is taught to children. The actual question you are likely to hear is usually not that formal and would be "*C'est quoi un Okapi ?*".

Comment: @jilliagre Thanks for such a detailed and descriptive answer! However, could you please explain to me why the last four phrases are incorrect? Did I not inverse the subject and the verb correctly for some of them? I also would like to know the clarification on "qui" and "que". Again, thank you for your response, but I need some more detailed on it.

Comment: @jlliagre Also I realize that "Qu'est-ce que c'est" doesn't refer to words, but for objects, as in "What is this?"

Comment: @jlliagre Finally, I think you made a mistake in your answer which you should edit: You wrote "exclamantion mark" but I think you meant "question mark"; an exclamation mark is "!" not "?".

Comment: Just want to underline *"Que veut dire ça"* which is not correct, but *"Que veut dire ceci?"* is.

Comment: @YohannV. But why is "ça" not correct and "ceci" is?

Comment: @user49558 As native, it is tearing my ears appart. I don't know exactly why. Just know that the correct form is : *"Qu'est-ce que ceci/cela veut dire?"*

Comment: @YohannV. Wait; that contradicts with jilliagre's answer where he/she said that "Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire?" is correct.

Comment: @user49558 It is, and it matches what you asked (using *"ça"*) but it is a talking vocabulary, the written proper form is *ceci/cela*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47933/discussion-between-user49558-and-yohann-v).